# Kubernetes pod cpu usage beyond the limits

Tags: kubernetes

I define the pod with limited resource:

`"resources": {
       "limits": {
        "cpu": "1",
        "memory": "4G"
       },
        "requests": {
          "cpu": "200m",
          "memory": "2G"
       }
    }`

The pod we limit it with 2 cpu， but it use more cpu actually, kubernetes do not kill the pod.

[image: CPU usage from zabbix]

Who have the same problem?

Comment: How many containers in your pod?

Comment: My pod have two container: Java Web(main container) and Debug Container(for debugging). Java Web container 's CPU usage exceed the cpu limits.

Comment: both of them has resource limit set?

Comment: yes, the QoS of two pods are Burstable, main pod limits set to 2C4G, debug pod limits set to 1C1G